# Why .net core documentation is wrong?

Tags: .net-core

This link for example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/individual?view=aspnetcore-2.1

```
dotnet new mvc -au Individual
dotnet new webapi -au Individual
dotnet new webapp -au Individual
```

[image]

**I dont see "webapp" in this list**

[image]

**Why does it throw an error:
Invalid input switch:
  -au**

I know for sure this switch exists.

[image]

**Why -h (help) switch is not working ??**

What invalid parameters? I just want to get help.

Comment: Did you see the note on that page that says: "If the `dotnet new webapp <OPTIONS>` command loads the dotnet new command help instead of creating a new Razor Pages app, install .NET Core SDK 2.1.300 or later. As of .NET Core SDK 2.1.300, **the `webapp` Short Name is an alias for `razor`**."

Comment: The `-au` switch requires a value, you're not providing one, hence the error which presumably stops it processing further switches (including the subsequent `-h`). Remove the `-au` and just use: `dotnet new webapp --help`

Comment: Is there a dotnet new webapi --au individual?